# void and return type

Tags: c

I have a c source file in which one of the method is defined as follows:

```
void QDECL prettyPrintf(int level) {
  ////// some code.
}
```

I would like to know what is QDECL.In this case, is it returning QDECL type? As far as  my  little knowledge in C, a 'void' does not return anything.So, is it a legal statement?

Comment: Go find the definition of QDECL - it'll expand to a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Nothing to do with the return type.

Comment: I never heard of it, but it seems to be an alias for __cdecl.

Comment: my concern here is that if I port the above code to Java, do I need to take care of this?

Comment: Minor nit: C doesn't have "methods", it has "functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the definition of QDECL. It is

```
#define QDECL   __cdecl
```

Now your declaration becomes,

```
void __cdecl prettyPrintf(int level)
```

which is *still* a function which returns void.

In fact `QDECL` can still take ( theoretically ) some other forms without altering the return type of your function. It easily could have been

```
#define QDECL static
```

Now, your function prototype is

```
void static prettyPrintf(int level)
```

which is still a `void` returning function

Answer (score 2):

`QDECL` is probably a preprocessor macro that resolves to a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) hint (e.g. `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`); This defines how parameters are pushed onto and cleaned up in the call stack, but it does not change the return type of the function. It is mainly used for interoperability when using libraries that use a different default calling convention than the client's.

Answer (score 1):

`QDECL` defines the calling convention. This is a macro defined in one of the header files that will evaluate to something like `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`.

This has no bearing on the return type of the function. The function is still a `void` function.

You state in a comment:

> My concern here is that if I port the above code to Java, do I need to take care of this?

No you do not. This is purely an issue for interfacing between different native libraries of code. Once the code is in Java you can simply ignore calling convention.

Comment: what advantage it brings during run time? any performance improvement?or is it coding style of the experts?

Comment: @UNNI It's not a question of performance, or advantages, or coding style. It's needed to define a binary contract between one library and another. This is a function that is exported in a shared library. And so all parties need to use the same rules when calling the function. The calling convention codifies those rules. Have a read of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention